# how to align menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just working on an eCommerce site where I am trying to create a **mega menu** using [CSS MEGA SITE NAVIGATION from Codyhouse](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-mega-site-navigation/).

Everything is perfect except the **horizontal alignment** of the 2nd level menu.

I tried positioning list but there is no use. 
Can anyone guide me to solve this?

Comment: We need code snipets... (css, html) so we can help you

Comment: @Sletheren okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the issue is that **float: left;** will continue to try and float as it moves down the page, taking the easiest option first (there's room at column 6, that's why it's chosen that one).

So, in addition to floating I would instruct the 8th column to clear each of the first 7 items, no matter their height.

I can't see what your HTML structure is but something like this should do the trick. Replace `li` whatever child element you're using.

```
li:nth-child(7n + 8){
  clear: both;
}
```

*To explain: 7n is the number of columns you want to have before starting a new row, and 8 is targeting the next column as you want this one to clear all of the first row's children.*

Comment: works great but having few gaps as you see in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfBJs.jpg. Is it possible to remove these gaps ??

Comment: On that same child, add a margin on the bottom - that should do the trick. In the future, it'll help people if you can do a jsfiddle of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ 

Hope all this helped! :)

Comment: as you suggested i added margin at bottom of child category but there is no use. i just created jsfiddle.net/pv5hb3L9 can you please have a look on this

Comment: Sorry, add margin-bottom to the <li>'s in general. I've updated the code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pv5hb3L9/2/